# How to implement this in functional programming using Function<T,R> in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, functional-programming

I have a scenario which in imperative programming would like this

```
processEvent(Event event) {
  if ( isEventOfSpecificType(event) ){ .............................................. 1

     Result result = findSomeData(event.someProperty()) ............................. 2
     if(result.someStatus == somevalue) { ........................................... 3

         saveEvent(event, result) // save to DB with properties from both objects ... 4
         String referenceID = createSomeRecord(event, result) // Will do API call ... 5
         writeToLogFile(event, result, referenceID) // write to a logfile ........... 6
     }
  }
}
```

I am trying to wrap my head around functional programming in JAVA using Function, Predicate, Consumer, and Supplier.

My first thought: use streams to take advantage of filter and map, but since there is no collection in this scenario it didn't seem appropriate to create a stream for one object.

My second thought: to use Function and curry, but I am lost. Not able to get my head around it since I need all the three objects in my last step.

How can this be done in a functional way. What are some of the best references to understand this topic.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to use `Function` (or `Stream`) here. You need to understand what tools are useful for what purpose. Java is not a functional programming language, and the `Function` interface doesn't make it one.

Comment: The first step in transforming this into a functional style, would be making `processEvent` *calculate a value*. What value is it calculating? What is the end result of "processing an event"? Perhaps the log line that you generate at the end of the method should be the return value?

Comment: @Joni Hello, transforming the OP code to a `Consumer` could be a valid option?

Comment: @dariosicily do you mean `Consumer<Event> eventConsumer = this::processEvent` ? That does not make the code any more functional than it already is

Comment: @Joni Yes because OP nominated Consumer in the post, unless as you said in the intentions of OP the log could represent the return value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Optional Apis to write above code but you need to follow functional programming approach.

Functional programming (often abbreviated FP) is the process of building software by composing pure functions, avoiding shared state, mutable data, and side-effects. Functional programming is declarative rather than imperative, and application state flows through pure functions. Contrast with object oriented programming, where application state is usually shared and colocated with methods in objects.

A pure function is a function which:

- Given the same inputs, always returns the same output, and
- Has no side-effects

You can read this blog:
https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-functional-programming-7f218c68b3a0

So in your case immutability is important.

```
    public void processEvent(final Event event) {
        Optional.of(event)
                .filter(this::isEventOfSpecificType)
                .map(e -> findSomeData(e.someProperty()))
                .ifPresent(r -> resultBiConsumer.accept(r, event));
    }

    private BiConsumer<Optional<Result>, Event> resultBiConsumer = (result, event) ->  {
            if(result.isPresent()) {
                Result r = result.get();
                if(r.getStatus() == 0) {
                    saveEvent(event, r);
                    String referenceID = createSomeRecord(event, r);
                    writeToLogFile(event, r, referenceID);
                }
            }
        };
```

Java code block on why immutability matters in functional programming.
https://belief-driven-design.com/functional-programming-with-java-immutability-ae3372311b9/